# FOS UserBundle and getting user

Tags: security, symfony, fosuserbundle

i'm a new Symfony2 developer, i'm using fos UserBundle to manage users and authentication.
i need to get the logged in user somewhere in my application (in another Bundle , not in the one in wish i implemented the FOS UserBUndle)
i found in the documentation that i should use this service:

```
$this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```

but it seems that the 'security.token_storage' was not recognized.
did i miss some use statements ?

Comment: What version of Symfony are you using? `@security.token_storage` was only introduced in 2.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution : i used this manipulation in a service or it shouldn't be.
so i move it to the controller and then it works

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is using the 'security.context' service like this :

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

Or even easier:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
```

Comment: Are both of them deprecated ?

Comment: Only the first option. The security.context service is deprecated. Use security.token_bag instead if you need to retrieve the token.